# Who? What Color? Rank? Number? in a running match

Tags: lateral-thinking

There is a running match, but there isn't anyone to judge; we have only information that the audience gave us (but we know their info is true). We the have name, rank, T-shirt color, and T-shirt number of each runner, as follows:

1. **Mahsa** won and she wore a red T-Shirt.
2. The girl who wore T-Shirt number 1 finished 3rd.
3. **Mahnaz**, who defeated a girl with a yellow T-Shirt, didn't wear number 2.
4. Only one girl got a rank that was as same as her T-shirt number; her T-shirt wasn't Red.
5. **Mozgan** defeated a girl wearing number 3 and **Maryam** wore the yellow T-Shirt.
6. The girl with green T-shirt wore number 2.
7. One of the girls had a blue T-shirt.

There were 4 runners.
Can you name the girls along with their rank (1 to 4), number, and color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed from the word "defeat" in hints 3 and 5 that coming coming 2nd and 3rd would both defeat the 4th place-holder which pointed to it being Maryam.

Ranking:-

1) Mahsa; Red; No.4

2) Mozgan; Green; No.2

3) Mahnaz; Blue; No.1

4) Maryam; Yellow; No.3

Comment: Forgot to use a comment. Still new to the site. And no problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Rank 1: Mahsa wearing red number 4
- Rank 2: Mozgan wearing green number 2
- Rank 3: Mahnaz wearing blue number 1
- Rank 4: Maryam wearing yellow number 3

This did not need more complicated means to solve.  All girls are listed as beating someone besides Maryam so she is last.  Mahsa can't wear 1, 2, or 3 as 1 got 3rd, 2 wore green, and 3 lost to someone.  (I assume 4 is the remaining number.) Maryam must wear 3 as 2 wore green and others are taken.  2 must have won second as it is the only one left.  Mahnaz must be 3rd as she didn't weat number 2.